# 'service' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, mysql, windows, xampp

I have installed XAMPP 7.4 and defined `mysql` as Environment Variable on my system, and then tried to run `service mysqld restart` on CMD but I got this:

```
F:\xampp\mysql\bin>service mysqld restart
'service' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So what is going wrong here? How can I run this command properly?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're trying to use a Unix command on Windows.

Comment: if you are using windows try to open the xamp program and there you can click on the start server for mysql

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, you need to use Run as Administrator to start your cmd.exe.

Then say

```
net stop mysql
net start mysql
```

and you should restart the mysql service.